# How to get all strokes/Rectangles which have been drawn on Frame by Graphics object?

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am very new to `Graphics2D` and `Frame` library. I was trying out `PDFRenderer`(from `PDFBox` library) to draw the pdf on a `Graphics2D` object. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;
public class Example01 extends Frame {
  /**
   * Instantiates an Example01 object.
   **/
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Example01();
  }
  /**
   * Our Example01 constructor sets the frame's size, adds the
   * visual components, and then makes them visible to the user.
   * It uses an adapter class to deal with the user closing
   * the frame.
   **/
  public Example01() {
    //Title our frame.
    super("Java 2D Example01");
    //Set the size for the frame.
    setSize(1000,1000);
    //We need to turn on the visibility of our frame
    //by setting the Visible parameter to true.
    setVisible(true);
    //Now, we want to be sure we properly dispose of resources
    //this frame is using when the window is closed.  We use
    //an anonymous inner class adapter for this.
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
      {public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
         {dispose(); System.exit(0);}
      }
    );
  }
  /**
   * The paint method provides the real magic.  Here we
   * cast the Graphics object to Graphics2D to illustrate
   * that we may use the same old graphics capabilities with
   * Graphics2D that we are used to using with Graphics.
   **/
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Users\\prabhjot.rai\\Desktop\\xceligent\\9542899.pdf")))
    {
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
        pdfRenderer.renderPageToGraphics(1, g2d);
        System.out.println(g2d.getStroke());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }
}
```

What this does is, creates a frame in which I can see the whole pdf. I am trying to get the strokes drawn inside the frame - using the graphics object. How can I get those? I am open to use any library other than frame, since my method `pdfRenderer.renderPageToGraphics(1, g2d)` requires only a `Graphics2D` object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible.

`Graphics2D` is an image based graphics tool, meaning that all actions you take are drawn to the image and forgotten, only the resulting pixels are stored.

The function `getStroke()` only return the current stroke, which will be used when you use any of the draw methods.

Many grahpics frameworks take a different approach (such as JavaFX), which supports drawing shapes and figures in a node based way, allowing you to decompose and change parts of the image (this renders the actual image after each change).